# How can I add routes to VPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn

```
client
dev tap
proto udp
remote ADDRESS PORT
auth-user-pass
ca cert-chain.pem
remote-cert-tls server

route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0

resolv-retry infinite

nobind

persist-key
persist-tun

verb 3

route-delay 3
redirect-gateway def1
```

I have the above OpenVPN configuration file and I want to connect from my SGS2.

Can you help me?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the official OpenVPN Client from the Play Store?

Answer (score 1):

I use this to access on ssh server from my Sony ericson (Arc S) (OS: android ice cream) via OVPN

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 41.204.120.234 1194
#Route option. I add this to access other IP not confugred on VPN server
route 10.162.100.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.8.4.0 255.255.255.0
...
#End of Route option
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/user.crt
key /etc/openvpn/user.key
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

If you use OVPN.